# How to hide mouse cursor in Microsoft Blazor after being inactive for sometime without using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, css, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

There is nothing much description here. All I want is to reduce JavaScript function call from Blazor to let the Blazor do what it is made for, "Avoid using JavaScript".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, answering here just to help future seekers of a similar problem without using complex coding.

Put the following code in the Index.razor file or any component of your choice where you want to hide the mouse cursor.

```
private bool _showMouse;
private static Timer _timer = new(_timerDuration);
private static double _timerDuration = 5000; //In my case, I wanted to hide the cursor after five seconds.

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _timer.Start();
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) 
{
    if (firstRender)
    {    
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _showMouse = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        };
    }
}

private void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
      _showMouse = true;
      _timer.Interval = 5000;
}
```

Add this to the In-Line style of your root element within which you would like your mouse to be hidden after a specified time of inactivity.

```html
<div @onmousemove="OnMouseMove" style="cursor: @(_showMouse ? "unset" : "none");">
  ...
  .
  .
  ...
</div>
```

Thank you. I hope it might help someone in the future!