# Is there a way to hide the mouse cursor in a MAUI/Blazor app?

Tags: windows, user-interface, maui, blazor-server-side

This is for a “kiosk” app running in Windows with a touchscreen. WebView2 doesn’t seem to support **cursor: none** style and I can’t see any way of doing the equivalent in MAUI. I'm looking for an equivalent to the old Win32 **ShowCursor()** function - but that doesn't seem to work with MAUI.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Does this case: [How to hide mouse cursor in Microsoft Blazor after being inactive for sometime without using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66917887/how-to-hide-mouse-cursor-in-microsoft-blazor-after-being-inactive-for-sometime-w) help?

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't think it does. As I said in my original message, WebView2 doesn’t seem to support cursor: none style. In fact, as far as I can tell, most cursor styles aren't supported by WebView2.

Comment: In this case, it should not be possible.